# How to indent new paragraphs?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

How can I change the `rmarkdown` settings in a way that a new paragraph starts with an indented first line (as the default in LateX) rather than with blank space and no indentation.

That is what I normally get:

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:**
```

[image]

That is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the header of your `Rmd` document, you can add LaTeX includes. To indent the paragraph, just change `parindent`, e.g.

```
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \setlength{\parindent}{4em}
  - \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
```

Alternatively, you could store the latex commands in a separate file:

```
includes:
   in_header: header.tex
```

See the [advanced customization](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#advanced_customization) section.

Comment: Thanks! However the blank space between two paragraphs remains. I guess the default tex template changes the way new paragraphs should be treated. Hence, I thought there might be a way to just silence this part in the `YAML` header.

Comment: `\parskip` controls the space between paragraphs: `\setlength{\parskip}{0em}`

Comment: @scoa Thanks. I came up with the same solution.

Comment: What about a first line indent? I used this and every paragraph is indented except for the paragraph that begins the section.